# Order table by most recent entry

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I am trying to create an app that is using a SQL database.
I want to show the newest entries from the table, but every time I run a command like `Select * from Table` I get the entries in the order they were introduced ( the one that I introduced a few weeks ago is the first one, and the one that I just introduced is the last one, at the bottom of the page)
How can I display them as I want (reverse to the order they were introduced)

Comment: If you want records in a particular order, then always use `order by` in your query.

Comment: there is an `order by` clause in sql. please go through that in the documentation.

Comment: To use Order by, I must introduce the date when I created the entry, right?

Comment: `order by your_date_column desc`, where descending means 'highest first'

Comment: If you're just starting out it's best to follow a complete tutorial, such as the one from microsoft to get a full idea of all that's possible - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you sir, I will follow that tutorial

Comment: Fields that indicate when a record was created and when it was last updated are often very useful.